# WPF Dependency Property Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, button, data-binding, combobox

I am wondering if anyone could explain me the difference between 
binding a selected value of a Collection to a comboBox.

Or Binding  the value to a Button Content.

Like that

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_culturedTitleViewModelSelector" Visibility="Hidden"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=_culturedTitleViewModelSelectorStyle}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableCultures, Source={x:Static Localized:ResourcesManager.Current}}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentCulture, Source={x:Static Localized:ResourcesManager.Current}}"


<Button x:Name="LanguageBtn" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentCulture, Source={x:StaticLocalized:ResourcesManager.Current}}"
```

The issue is If i Don't use the ComboBox up there, the DependencyProperty I Have in another class is not being called.

But if I Use the comboBox everything works...
Altought the comboBox doesnt do anything it's just a "workarround"
In my CS code when i CLick on my button I DO that :

```
        ResourcesManager.Current.SwitchToNextCulture();
        //We use a dummy comboBox to make sure the LanguageBehavior Property is being notified.
        _culturedTitleViewModelSelector.SelectedItem = ResourcesManager.Current.CurrentCulture;
```

And if I Dont set the SelectedItem of the combobox to another culture. My languageBehavior class is not notified.

:

```
public class LanguageBehavior
{
    public static DependencyProperty LanguageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Language",
                                            typeof(string),
                                            typeof(LanguageBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(OnLanguageChanged));

    public static void SetLanguage(FrameworkElement target, string value)
    {
        target.SetValue(LanguageProperty, value);
    }
    public static string GetLanguage(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        return (string)target.GetValue(LanguageProperty);
    }

    private static void OnLanguageChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = target as FrameworkElement;
        if (e.NewValue!=null)
        element.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(e.NewValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'd expect ComboBox Content to work the same as Button Content.

In my Generic.Xaml i do that :

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="_textBlockLanguageProperty">
    <Setter Property="WpfServices:LanguageBehavior.Language" Value="{Binding Path=CurrentCulture, Source={x:Static Localized:ResourcesManager.Current}}" 
        />
</Style>
```

And that is CurrentCulture

```
  public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
    {
        get { return CultureProvider.Current; }
        set
        {
            if (value != CultureProvider.Current)
            {
                CultureProvider.Current = value;
                OnCultureChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Current :

```
    public static ResourcesManager Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resourcesManager == null)
            {
                var cultureProvider = new BaseCultureProvider();
                _resourcesManager = new ResourcesManager(cultureProvider);
                _resourcesManager.Init();
            }
            return _resourcesManager;
        }
    }
```

EDIT :

My _culturedTitelViewModelSelectorStyle is

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="_culturedTitleViewModelSelectorStyle">
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="DisplayName" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="." />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
</Style>
```

Comment: What is your `_culturedTitleViewModelSelectorStyle`?

Comment: Hi Lukazoid See my edit at the buttom.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ComboBox` you are binding the `SelectedValue` to a specific culture.  This will select that culture from the list of available cultures, and therefor, trigger a set on the `CurrentCulture` property.

The `Content` property of a `Button` is merely displaying something to the user, it is not doing any assigning.  It reads the property value and then displays it.  That is why you need to manually change the Culture in the `Click` event to get it to do anything.

If you want the user to be able to select a value from a list of available values, a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` is the way to go.  A `Button` is for triggering a specific action, not for selecting from a list.

Comment: Hi Brian, that is not what i meant.
I am using the content{Binding Path=} of the button and it doesnt change when i change the property from code.

Tho If i do the same from the comboBox the content of the button changes.